# Formato da data no php

Tags: php, data

Como mudar o formato da data de 2016-2-26 para 26/02/2016.
Já tentei utilizar o format, mas não deu certo.

Comment: O ideal é que coloque o código que já tentou

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$time = strtotime('2016-2-26');

$data_formatada = date('d/m/Y',$time);

echo $data_formatada;
```

Vai imprimir:

> 26/02/2016

Answer (score 0):

Jeito mais simples de fazer, trabalhando como *String*, transformando a data em um array com *explode*. Não sei se te ajuda ou se queria trabalhar como data mesmo. Segue abaixo:

```
<?php

$data = '2016-2-26';
$array = explode('-', $data);
$data = $array[2].'/0'.$array[1].'/'.$array[0];
print($data);
```

Caso não seja isto, informe que posso apagar a resposta.

Comment: Encontrei essa forma:

date('d/m/Y',  strtotime($var))